# Fetching facebook user's name from python without access token

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, dialogflow-es

How can I get a user's name, who is already conversing with my bot on messenger? I have researched alot but cannot seem to get a single piece of information to get the name in an easier way (without the access token). I just think it should be easier to get the name (basic!) than getting the email and other information. I have tried getting it using the user access token, but it doesnt seem to work - returns Response[400]. Please point out if there is anything wrong with the code:

```
fields = "name"
```

url="https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/"+"User_ID"+"fields="+fields+"&access_token="+access_token

```
payload = json.load(open("request.json"))
print("line 135")
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept-Charset': 'UTF-8'}
r = requests.get(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Although, I'd stll prefer a way to get it without the user id and access token.
Thanks!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/user-profile

Answer (score 0):

Found a great way to do this here: https://github.com/abhay1/django-facebook-messenger-bot-tutorial/blob/master/yomamabot/fb_yomamabot/views.py#L34

Thanks Abhay!